# Convert URL to file system path

Tags: php

Is there a way to convert a web URL in to the absolute file system path (independent from OS)?

For example: I have an URL `/images/test.jpg` (`http://www.example.com/images/test.jpg`) and I need to get:

- `c:\path\to\webroot\images\test.jpg`` on Windows,
- `/var/path/to/webroot/images/test.jpg` on Linux.

Any way to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$str = "/images/test.jpg";
$str = realpath("." . $str);
```

Comment: The idea is good, but you should remove the leading `/` or put a `.` in front of it.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. Of course  I have to use the `.` only if my php file is in the webroot directory, if it's in a subdirectory or I need `..`

Answer (score 3):

This will give you `/images/test.jpg`:

```
$path = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $path)
```

Where `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` gives you the document root directory under which the current script is executing.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want the [realpath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) function.